# JAVA INSERT INTO SELECT, Is it possible?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

it's possible to do an "INSERT INTO SELECT" using **NamedParameterJdbcTemplate**?
I want to do that because I have a lot of columns that I wont use, so I think that using select it will be easier.

Is it possible?

```
@Override
    public void insertIntoSelect(SomeDTO some) {
        try {
            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
            sql.append("INSERT INTO ");
            sql.append("    EXAMPLE_DB ");
            sql.append("SELECT ");
            sql.append("    COLUMN1, ");
            sql.append("    COLUMN2, ");
            sql.append("    COLUMN3, ");
            sql.append("    :testParam, ");
            sql.append("    COLUMN5, ");
            sql.append("FROM ");
            sql.append("    EXAMPLE_DB ");
            sql.append("WHERE ");
            sql.append("    COLUMN1 = :firstParam ");
            sql.append("    AND COLUMN2 = :secondParam ");

            MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            param.addValue("firstParam", some.getSomeData());
            param.addValue("secondParam", some.getSomeDataTwo());
            param.addValue("testParam", some.getTestParam());

            new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource).update(sql.toString(), param);
        } catch (BadSqlGrammarException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Example Error." + e);
            throw new BadSqlGrammarException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Is it possible?", did you try and if so what issue/error did you experience?

Comment: Yes, I tried but I always get a badSqlGrammarException, if I remove this part sql.append("    :testParam, "), the code runs.

Comment: You can't have a column name as a parameter to your sql. If you want to use different columns you need to solve that in the java code when building the sql query.

Comment: So it's impossible to do an update using select statement in java? There are other ways to do that, or I must have to populate my DTO with **all** columns that exists inside my table?

Comment: What database are you using. And what is the original BadSqlGrammarException you are getting?

Comment: Sorry; I misread the sql query so you can forget what I said earlier. You should be able to use a parameter like you do now. Looking at this again the issue might be that you need to list the columns you are inserting into as well, `INSERT INTO Column1, Column2,...`. See my answer below

Comment: Which database are you using? You may need to add an explicit cast around a parameter in the `select`-clause depending on the database system.

Comment: Joakim, I'll try It.

Comment: Mark, I'm using IBM DB2

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, do you know what cast should I use for DB2?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use DB2, but in some database doing `cast(:testParam as integer)` (or whatever the type is) works.

Comment: I did the same as the example, but doesn't work :/

Answer (score -1):

I think you can not use a parameter as a column name.
Rather you can modify like StringBuilder like

```
String testParam = some.getTestParam();
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
         sql.append("INSERT INTO ");
         sql.append("    EXAMPLE_DB ");
         sql.append("SELECT ");
         sql.append("    COLUMN1, ");
         sql.append("    COLUMN2, ");
         sql.append("    COLUMN3, ");
         sql.append("   " + testParam + ",");
         sql.append("    COLUMN5, ");
         sql.append("FROM ");
         sql.append("    EXAMPLE_DB ");
         sql.append("WHERE ");
         sql.append("    COLUMN1 = :firstParam ");
         sql.append("    AND COLUMN2 = :secondParam ");
```

Replace **sql.append("    :testParam, ");**  with **sql.append("   " + testParam + ",");**  will work

Comment: This is unsafe and makes the code vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: SQL injection is possible if i directly use variables in where condition. I am using named parameters in conditions, and in select we can not use named parameters and sql injection is not possible in this case

Comment: You are inserting the value of `testParam` into the query string. Depending on where `testParam` is sourced, it can open you up to SQL injection.